# Getting nsIChannel request's nsIDOMWindow always returns null on e10s

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, multiprocess

I have an [observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Observer_Notifications) on "http-on-modify-request" and I need to get the [DOMWindow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIDOMWindow) that request is associated with.

The following code was taken from [AdBlock Plus](https://adblockplus.org/) and is based on [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser#Getting_the_browser_that_fires_the_http-on-modify-request_notification_(example_code_updated_for_loadContext)).

```
function getRequestWindow(/**nsIChannel*/ channel) /**nsIDOMWindow*/
  {
    try
    {
      if (channel.notificationCallbacks)
        return channel.notificationCallbacks.getInterface(Ci.nsILoadContext).associatedWindow;
    } catch(e) {}

    try
    {
      if (channel.loadGroup && channel.loadGroup.notificationCallbacks)
        return channel.loadGroup.notificationCallbacks.getInterface(Ci.nsILoadContext).associatedWindow;
    } catch(e) {}

 return null;
}
```

However, this code is no longer working on multiprocess Firefox (v36+, right now on [Firefox Nightly](https://nightly.mozilla.org/)).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried that myself, so take with a grain of salt:

Instead of getting the nsIDOMWindow itself from the channel you can get the innerWindowId from the nsIChannel.loadInfo. The window id can then be resolved inside a frame script by `QueryInterface`ing to [nsIDOMWindowUtils](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIDOMWindowUtils#Attributes).

Answer (score 0):

To talk to content, the recommended path for this sort of use case is probably [Frame Scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox/Frame_script_environment), see this documentation on MDN for more.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use this, could you please provide an example?
I don't need to actually access the DOM content, I just need to get the tab so I know which page made HTTP request.